# Extract labels from Tensorflowdataset Imagenet_subset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, imagenet

I am studying electrical engineering and doing some ML-stuff on hardware level.

I downloaded the Imagenet_subset using tensorflowdataset:

```
ds = tfds.load('imagenet2012_subset',
                data_dir=os.path.join(write_dir, 'data'),
                #split='validation',
                shuffle_files=False,
                download=True,
                as_supervised=True,
                download_and_prepare_kwargs=download_and_prepare_kwargs,
                with_info=False)
```

Currently I am preparing the data like that:

```
def resize_with_crop(image, label):
       i = image
       i = tf.cast(i, tf.float32)
       #i = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(i, 224, 224)
       i = tf.image.resize(i, size=(224, 224))
       #i = tf.expand_dims(i, axis=0)
       i = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input(i)
       return (i, label)

train = ds['train']
val = ds['validation']
# Preprocess the images
ds_train = train.map(resize_with_crop)
ds_val = val.map(resize_with_crop)
```

Now comes the filthy part. The way I extract the images and labels:

```
label= []
img = []

for element in ds_val.take(10000).as_numpy_iterator():
img.append(element[0])
label.append(element[1])
img = np.asarray(img)
label = np.asarray(label)
```

This approach is working but kind of ugly and killing my RAM.

Does some of you know how to extract the labels and images in a clean way?

The model I used is the MobileNetV2 pretrained on Imagenet:

```
model = keras.applications.MobileNetV2()
```

Thank you!

Comment: `ds_train` and `ds_val` should already contain the images and labels as arrays. I'm not sure the exact object name with this method, but if you debug and look at either of those two, you'll find the arrays, they'll most likely be top level For example, `dataset` from `ImageDataGenerator` will have `dataset.classes` and `dataset.class_indices` for images and labels, respectively. No need to build a new set of arrays `label` and `img` when they already exist. You then just take your 10000 from there.

Comment: Yeah, you are right but when I try to train with the ds_train I get this error message:
'ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.'

Comment: Your model is trying to perform an operation on data that doesn't exist. Can you update your question with how you defined your model?

Comment: I did use the pretrained MobileNetV2 from keras.
Thank you for trying to help me

Comment: What's the output of `ds.shape` or `ds_train.shape` or `ds_val.shape`?

Comment: for `ds.shape` : `'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'`
for `ds_val` and `ds_train`: `'PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: Sorry, try `tf.shape(ds_train)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I found a solution.
For all facing similar problems, I used this line:
`train_ds = train_examples.map(imagenet_preprocessing, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).shuffle(buffer_size=5000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)`